# Auto apply backslash to pasted text in iTerm2, that contains '?' (indicator to the start of query string in URL)

Tags: url, iterm2, oh-my-zsh, escape-characters

Previously, I could paste a website URL (Ex. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID`) after copying from the browser URL section, onto iTerm2 window.

It would escape the *question mark* and *equal sign*, to give the resultant string as

> `https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v\=VIDEO_ID`

What (according to me) has caused the issue:

> I changed the **`Key Mappings`** from `xterm Defaults` to `Natural Text Editting`, in the `Preferences > Profiles > Keys` section, so that I could use the `Option + LEFT_ARROW` and `Option + RIGHT_ARROW` to navigate between words.

What have I tried so far:

> I have tried to set the **`Key Mappings`** back to `xterm Defaults`, and pasted the URL. But it is still not able to put a backslash (`\`) before each of `?` and `=` characters as it used to, before.

What is the behavior I want to see now ?

> When I paste a URL in iTerm2, I would want some characters like `?` and `=` to be escaped in the pasted string as shown above (Escaping `=` is not completely necessary for the answer, though I would want to know how it could be done).

---

**EDIT (after New Info Discovery)**

> It would escape the question mark and equal sign ...

The `It` (blockquoted above) was seen again after I reinstalled `oh-my-zsh`. Now I want to know where is that change being applied from within `oh-my-zsh`, so that I can make that change myself without using `oh-my-zsh`?

(Full Disclosure: I'm not a fan of this bloated `oh-my-zsh` plugins manager)